# Would this be a valid Implementation of an ordinal CrossEntropy?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, statistics

Would this be a valid implementation of a cross entropy loss that takes the ordinal structure of the GT `y` into consideration? `y_hat` is the prediction from a neural network.

```
ce_loss = F.cross_entropy(y_hat, y, reduction="none")
distance_weight = torch.abs(y_hat.argmax(1) - y) + 1
ordinal_ce_loss = torch.mean(distance_weight * ce_loss)
```

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "ordinal structure"

Comment: Interesting question, however, it's off topic here; for further questions of this kind, try stats.stackexchange.com or maybe datascience.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer this question by first fully defining the task, since the question is a bit sparse on details.

> I have a set of ordinal classes (e.g. first, second, third, fourth,
> etc.) and I would like to predict the class of each data example from
> among this set. I would like to define an entropy-based loss-function
> for this problem. I would like this loss function to weight the loss
> between a predicted class `torch.argmax(y_hat)` and the true class `y`
> according to the ordinal distance between the two classes. Does the
> given loss expression accomplish this?

**Short answer:** sure, it is "valid". You've roughly implemented L1-norm ordinal class weighting. I'd question whether this is truly the correct weighting strategy for this problem.

1. For instance, consider that for a true label `n`, the bin `n` response is weighted by 1, but the bin `n+1` and `n-1` responses are weighted by 2. This means that a lot more emphasis will be placed on NOT predicting false positives than on correctly predicting true positives, which may imbue your model with some strange bias.
2. It also means that examples on the edge will result in a larger total sum of weights, meaning that you'll be weighting examples where the true label is say "first" or "last" more highly than the intermediate classes. (Say you have 5 classes: 1,2,3,4,5. A true label of 1 will require `distance_weight` of [1,2,3,4,5], the sum of which is 15. A true label of 3 will require `distance_weight` of [3,2,1,2,3], the sum of which is 11.
3. In general, classification problems and entropy-based losses are underpinned by the assumption that no set of classes or categories is any more or less related than any other set of classes. In essence, the input data is embedded into an orthogonal feature space where each class represents one vector in the basis. This is quite plainly a bad assumption in your case, meaning that this embedding space is probably not particularly elegant: thus, you have to correct for it with sort of a hack-y weight fix. And in general, this assumption of class non-correlation is probably not true in a great many classification problems (consider e.g. the classic ImageNet classification problem, wherein the class pairs [bus,car], and [bus,zebra] are treated as equally dissimilar. But this is probably a digression into the inherent lack of usefulness of strict ontological structuring of information which is outside the scope of this answer...)

**Long Answer**: I'd highly suggest moving into a space where the ordinal value you care about is instead expressed in a continuous space. (In the first, second, third example, you might for instance output a continuous value over the range [1,max_place]. This allows you to benefit from loss functions that already capture well the notion that predictions closer in an ordered space are better than predictions farther away in an ordered space (e.g. MSE, Smooth-L1, etc.)

Let's consider one more time the case of the [first,second,third,etc.] ordinal class example, and say that we are trying to predict the places of a set of runners in a race. Consider two races, one in which the first place runner wins by 30% relative to the second place runner, and the second in which the first place runner wins by only 1%. This nuance is entirely discarded by the ordinal discrete classification. In essence, the selection of an ordinal set of classes    truncates the amount of information conveyed in the prediction, which means not only that the final prediction is less useful, but also that the loss function encodes this strange truncation and binarization, which is then reflected (perhaps harmfully) in the learned model. This problem could likely be much more elegantly solved by regressing the finishing position, or perhaps instead by regressing the finishing time, of each athlete, and then performing the final ordinal classification into places OUTSIDE of the network training.

In conclusion, you might expect a well-trained ordinal classifier to produce essentially a normal distribution of responses across the class bins, with the distribution peak on the true value: a binned discretization of a space that almost certainly could, and likely should, be treated as a continuous space.